# @font-face rendering bigger in Chrome/IE, fontsquirrel

Tags: css, font-face

Im using @font-face to render a custom font on a site
the font is 'Ministry ExtraLight' 
Im also using this website to generat font files http://www.fontsquirrel.com.

it looks fine on FireFox. but on Chrome/IE/Safari it looks like the font is bloded.
when I inspect the font, its actually set to

```
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant:normal
```

but it renders bold or added weight to the font.

has any one bumped into anything like that?

[image: Rendering on Chrome/FF]

Comment: What if you hard code font-weight ?

Answer (score 1):

That is not entirely the truth - I encountered exactly the same problem the font in firefox and opera is rendered thin on font-weight normal but webkits render it bold - when I apply the font weight bold to the styles in all browsers they look the same. So the firefox is not the odd one out here but webkits are rendering it wrong and ignoring the font weight.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also find differences in rendering between Windows, OSX, and Linux.

It sounds like Firefox is the odd one out, so you should probably look for what's different there.

What may be happening is that Firefox uses its own font rendering, while the others are using the system font rendering. If you have your system set to change the fonts (make them bolder, turn on various types of anti-aliasing, etc.) you may see the described effect.

Comment: my FF isnt set to alter anyt fonts, its set to default. and its happenign other machines too. the font looks alot closer to how FF renders it than other other 3 browers ive tested.

Comment: There's no "setting". What's happening is that it's using a different rendering engine. A browser can use the one supplied by the system, or it can use its own. Firefox is using its own. There's absolutely no way to make the three browsers render the font precisely the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find any way to fix it, use Cufon
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: I was using cufon but it makes everything so slwo

Answer (score 0):

Whilst what Paul said is right (about rendering) something else you can try is including the reset/fonts css declarations from Yahoo!

They do a pretty good job of leveling the field between browsers, albeit, you are basically getting rid of how each browser displays elements, so you will have to define all your elements styles from the ground up.

ref:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssfonts/ , http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing.

Since i found no solution, i went over to use the same font on Google Webfont's instead.

http://www.google.com/webfonts

The bad thing is that Googles webfonts are much larger (Open Sans is ~2-3 times larger than font-squirrel's Open Sans), so watch out.